# Great biking cities and routes in Europe?

Tags: city

I just returned from a great weekend of biking in Berlin.  Riding there was pure pleasure due to the number of bike lanes and easy day routes to interesting sites around the city.

I know this is not a question with a single correct answer but I would love recommendations on other great biking cities in Europe?

Comment: As you stated in your question, this is not a real question with a singe correct answer; it's better suited to a web forum. Nevertheless, welcome to the site, and please read our FAQ.

Comment: Ok, no prob.  :-)

Comment: The regional forums at [Bikeforums](http://www.bikeforums.net/forumdisplay.php/243-Europe) are quite good for this.

Answer (score 1):

The [Copenhagenize Index](http://copenhagenize.eu/index/) ranks the top 20 cities by bike friendliness in 13 categories. It's a world-wide index, but most of the top 20 are in Europe.

The European cities that made the top 20 are:

- Amsterdam (54)
- Copenhagen (52)
- Barcelona (45)
- Berlin (41)
- Munich (40)
- Paris (39)
- Dublin (37)
- Budapest (36)
- Hamburg (36)
- Stockholm (33)
- Helsinki (31)
- London (31)
- Vienna (30)

Answer (score 0):

+1 for London. The Thames and the Parks are brilliant places to ride, and for getting across town.

You also have Sustrans routes, sign-posted, looked after and online:

http://www.sustrans.org.uk/map?key=London&type=RG

Transport for London also have a cycling journey planner:

http://www.tfl.gov.uk/roadusers/cycling/11598.aspx

Some people complain about cycling infrastructure in London, but it all comes down to what you know, and I know there is no need to get across London any other way than by bike.

Comment: I'm not sure that "Riding there was pure pleasure" really applies though ...

Comment: Fantastic sights, the thrills and spills of playing cat 'n' mouse with the tin box occupiers, plenty of places to actually want to visit, an amazing parallel way of getting around via the parks, canals and river, no hills to speak of - what more could you want?!?!!